# Why won't my UIView show a UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uikit, uisearchbar

I want to set a UIView in my storyboard equal to the `UISearchBar` of my `UISearchController` For some reason this code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var theView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here..."
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    theView = searchController.searchBar

}
```

Won't display the search bar. But this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tblSearchResults: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here..."
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    tblSearchResults.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}
```

will. Why? The `UITableView` header view is a `UIView` so why is it behaving differently?

Comment: you do not call addSubview on the `theView`

Comment: @Shubhank Do I have to add it as a subview? I really would like to just set it as the view.

Answer (score 0):

Not going to give any advice on why you want to do it this way, but in order to help solve your specific problem...

Check... after assigning, `searchController.searchBar` reference is copied to `theView`.  The searchBar has no superview, so not `theView` does not either.  You can then either add the `searchController.searchBar` or `theView` back as a subview as they both have the same reference.

```
@IBOutlet weak var theView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here..."
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    print("theView0 \(theView.superview)")

    theView = searchController.searchBar
    print("theView1 \(theView.superview)") //notice this is nil now

    view.addSubview(theView) //OR view.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)

    print("theView2 \(theView.superview)")
}
```